# jmeter just request for GET /

Tags: jmeter

I'm using Jmeter HTTP request to examine my website's performance. my website has many pictures but jmeter just request for / ! (example of request that it sends`GET http://example.com`) 
how can I make to act like a normal user? (I mean request for every component of the page)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to mimic browser cookies
2. Configure [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to [download embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) (images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc)
3. Add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to simulate browser cache
4. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) and other headers which real browser sends
5. If your application is built using [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) technology - put asynchronous requests triggered by JavaScript under the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller)